# Report rows differ from SQL result

Tags: reporting-services

I am stumped.

I have a select statement that returns the data fine in the data pane, but in the resulting report, one row is our of sort order and falls about 25 rows down in the data where it shouldn't be.

How do I trouble shoot something like that?

Thanks!i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in the report you must be sorting the dataset. In this case, the data will look fine in the data pane but will be out of the expected order in the report.  Try adding a brand new table to the report and apply the dataset. It should match the data pane.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that! I DID reuse this report from an existing report and I bet there is sorting in it...I did look but couldn't remember where that sorting would be found. It has been a long while since the original report was done.

Comment: +1: That was going to be my suggestion.  If things are still weird, refresh the dataset by going to the **Data** tab, selecting the dataset from the drop down (if there's more than one), and click the refresh button to the left of the dropdown (it's tiny, looks like a recycling logo)

Comment: New table. That did the trick! Thanks. I wonder where the grouping was? In the future I'd like to just find it and change it.

Comment: Try right-clicking on the table and select properties.  In the resulting window, there should be sorting and grouping tabs (I don't have SSRS open right now so I can't remember exactly.). The source of the incorrectly ordered data should be somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I trouble shoot something like that?

You start by posting the `select` statement here so we can help without having to hone our psychic debugging skills :-)

It's possible that you're not ordering on *every* column you think you are. It's also possible that SSRS re-orders the data even after you've retrieved it.

They'd be the first two places I'd look.

Comment: The key thing is that when I execute the SQL in the data pane, it returns everything properly sorted on 3 columns. I can scroll through it, and it's all fine. The report has that one row out of place, and I can't see anything special about that row.  Thanks for the suggestion.